# sql statement to check user have in any room

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

what i want to do is 1 user only can in 1 room if he want second room he must leave the previous.

what i was facing is i can in any room and if i reenter any room the modal message pop. Seem like my statement is going wrong == i have a hard time with this.Can anyone point out the wrong that i have?

the table is name as chatroom_user cloumns = `chatroom_id | user_id`

```
chatroom_id is link with chatroom table
user_id is link with user table
```

this is my code

```
<?php

include '../config.php';

$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$chatroomid=$_GET['chatroomID'];

$chatroomname=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT name from chatroom Where id='$chatroomid'");
$getchatroomname=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($chatroomname);

$check_data=  mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id='$chatroomid' AND user_id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$check=  mysqli_num_rows($check_data);

$checkUserDataInAnyRoom =  mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id='2' AND user_id=1 ");
$checkUser=  mysqli_num_rows($checkUserDataInAnyRoom);

if($check==0){

    $update_status="INSERT INTO chatroom_user (`chatroom_id`,`user_id`)VALUES ('$chatroomid','$id')";
    $check_status=mysqli_query($connection,$update_status)or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $count=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * from chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id ='$chatroomid' ")or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $total_user_in_any_chatroom = mysqli_num_rows($count);

        echo " Total User : ". $total_user_in_any_chatroom. " " ;  
    }
    elseif ($checkUser == 0) {
        echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('#remind-user-chatroom').modal('show'); });</script>
                <a href='chatrooms.php'>
                    <div class ='modal fade' id ='remind-user-chatroom' role ='dialog'>
                        <div class ='modal-dialog'>
                            <div class ='modal-content'>
                                <div class ='modal-header'>
                                    <button type='class' class ='close' data-dismiss ='modal'>&times;</button>
                                    <label class ='modal-title'>Reminder</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class ='modal-body'>
                                    <span>You haven't leave previous chatroom. Please leave it and re-enter back. Thank You</span>
                                        <div class ='submit-container'>
                                            <button type='button' class='btn content-btn'>Leave</button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </a>";  
    }
    else{
        $count=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * from chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id ='$chatroomid' ")or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $total_user_in_any_chatroom = mysqli_num_rows($count);

        echo " Total User : ". $total_user_in_any_chatroom. " " ;
    }
```

?>

Comment: is there an error message? and escape the data or you will get sql injection problems

Comment: i didnt get any error message== this is the main problem i cant find which part is the problem or maybe my logic thinking is no that good==

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"SELECT name from chatroom Where id='$chatroomid'"
"SELECT * FROM chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id='$chatroomid' AND user_id='$id'"
"INSERT INTO chatroom_user (`chatroom_id`,`user_id`)VALUES ('$chatroomid','$id')"
"SELECT * from chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id ='$chatroomid' "
```

to

```
"SELECT name from chatroom Where id='".$chatroomid."'"
"SELECT * FROM chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id='".$chatroomid."' AND user_id='".$id."'"
"INSERT INTO chatroom_user (`chatroom_id`,`user_id`)VALUES ('".$chatroomid."','".$id."')"
"SELECT * from chatroom_user WHERE chatroom_id ='".$chatroomid."' "
```